# SQL - Display name instead of ID

Tags: sql

I have two tables `DragRace` and `Team`:

**dragrace**

id  |  date  | team_one_id | team_two_id | tournament_id

**team**

id  | name

What I am trying to do is display the names instead of ID's with the date and only tournament_id 3.

I'm new to SQL and really not sure how to change the ID for the name. I read something about using WHILE() but its mySQL and as I understood its not supported yet.

I'm trying something like this;

```
SELECT dragrace.date, team.name AS teamOne, team.name AS teamTwo 
FROM dragrace, team 
WHERE tournament_id = 3;
```

Can I then use the teamOne and TeamTwo tags to add the names where dragrace.teamone_id = team.id?

help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to understand [`JOIN`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit help! And PM 77-1 for the tip! Im gonna read more about JOIN.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Thanks sir, nice link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the team table twice: once for each team in the `dragrace` table:

```sql
    SELECT d.date, t1.name AS teamOne, t2.name AS teamTwo 
    FROM dragrace d 
    JOIN team t1 ON  d.team_one_id = t1.id
    JOIN team t2 ON d.team_two_id = t2.id
    WHERE tournament_id = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, daShier! That was super quick! Ive been sitting for hours with this :P

Answer (score 0):

Here give this a try

```
SELECT d.date, d.team_one_id As teamOne, t.name, d.team_two_id As teamTwo, h.name
FROM ((dragrace d 
INNER JOIN team t ON d.team_one_id = t.id)
INNER JOIN team h ON d.team_two_id = h.id)
WHERE d.tournament_id = '3'
```

Not sure if it's that efficient but it should give you the result your looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Breau! I wasnt sure how to implement the JOIN(s) so this really helped.